# Editing RPGLE-Code directly from the ifs?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-ifs, rational-developer-for-i

does anyone know how to edit rpg code stored in the ifs with the rational developer?

I only get the following view without outline or highlighting etc.
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EvQb.png)

thanks in advance
paul

Comment: I've never had a problem.  For me (RDI 9.6.0.5), it works automatically just like source members.  Are you in the correct perspective?

Comment: Have you tried adding the outline view from the Window menu?

Comment: i'm in the remote system explorer perspective. is it the right one or do i have to use another one?

Comment: The perspective doesn't matter, but that is the one I use for all IBM i files (even device files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are missing views in a perspective you want to use, just add them from the menu `Window -> Show View -> Other...` (choose the view you want)

If you are not getting the editor you want Right click on the file and choose the editor you want by selecting `Open With`, then selecting the appropriate editor.

You can set the default editor for a file type by updating the File Associations for the file type. There are two places that you might do this in `Window -> Preferences`. First is File Associations:

1. In the Preferences dialog, type `File Associations` in the filter text field.
2. Select `General -> Editors -> File Associations`
3. Find the extension for your file in the right hand panel of the dialog, and select it.
4. Make sure the correct editor is associated with the file type, and if not add it. You can also select a default here.

The above way to set file associations affects files in the IFS. To check or set file associations in the QSYS library system:

1. Go back to the Preferences dialog and type `Parser Associations` in the filter text field.
2. Select `LPEX Editor -> Parsers -> Parser Associations`
3. In the right hand panel, make sure that the source type exists, and it is associated with the correct parser type.